# Search and Replace Words in HTML

Tags: php, javascript, regex, dom, replace

what I'm trying to do is make a 'jargon buster'.
Basically I have some html and some glossary terms in a database.
When the person clicks on jargon buster it replaces the words in the text with a nice tooltip (wztooltip) which shows them the meanings.

I've been trying hard on this one and been looking heavily at this question
[Regex / DOMDocument - match and replace text not in a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044812/regex-domdocument-match-and-replace-text-not-in-a-link)

and it seems like the answer lies in the simple_html_dom libs but I'm having trouble getting it to work.
Obviously any words already linked don't get touched. 
Here is a strip down of what I've got.

```
$html = str_get_html($article['content']);

$query_glossary = "SELECT word,glossary_term_id,info FROM glossary_terms WHERE status = 1  ORDER BY LENGTH(word) DESC";
$result_glossary = mysql_query_run($query_glossary);

while($glossary = mysql_fetch_array($result_glossary)) {
    $glossary_link = SITEURL.'/glossary/term/'.string_to_url($glossary['word']).'-'.$glossary['glossary_term_id'];
    if(strlen($glossary['info'])>400) {
        $glossary_info = substr(strip_tags($glossary['info']),0,350).' ...<br /> <a href="'.$glossary_link.'">Read More</a>';
    }
    else {
        $glossary_info = $glossary['info'];
    }
    $glossary_tip = 'href="javascript:;" onmouseout="UnTip();" class="article_jargon_highligher" onmouseover="'.tooltip_javascript('<a href="'.$glossary_link.'">'.$glossary['word'].'</a>',$glossary_info,400,1,0,1).'"';
    $glossary_word = $glossary['word'];
    $glossary_word = preg_quote($glossary_word,'/');

    //once done we can replace the words with a nice tip    
    foreach ($html->find('text') as $element) {
        if (!in_array($element->parent()->tag,array())) {
            //problems are case aren't taken into account and grammer
            $element->innertext = str_ireplace(''.$glossary['word'].' ',' <a '.$glossary_tip.' >'.$glossary['word'].'</a> ', $element->innertext);

           //$element->innertext = str_ireplace(''.$glossary['word'].',',' <a '.$glossary_tip.'>'.$glossary['word'].'</a> ', $element->innertext);
           //$element->innertext = preg_replace ("/\s(".$glossary_word.")\s/ise","nothing(' <a'.'$glossary_tip.'>'.'$1'.'</a> ')" , $element->innertext);
          // $element->innertext = str_replace('__glossary_tip_replace__',$glossary_tip, $element->innertext);
        }
    }
}
$article['content'] = $html->save();
```

Comment: I'm a colleague . The real problem is that we are having trouble getting the code to only match invidiaul words and not words inside words (ie: APS in perhaps). These words are within HTML as well. So that needs considering.

Comment: It's surely just a case of writing a powerful enough regex, probably using whitespace and punctuation to detect word boundaries, although I won't embarrass myself by trying. +1

Comment: Do you want a JS solution or a PHP solution, because you used both tags?

Comment: Hi, I wrote a Wikimedia extension a while back that does something similar. Depending on your approach, it's very easy to end up with an inefficient solution. It might help you to take a look: https://github.com/bcoughlan/Extension-Lingo/blob/master/Lingo.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the inverted word character `\W` to select for any characters other than numbers and letters in your regex pattern. Because this would still fail at the boundaries of the text blob, you would also need to test those conditions as well. Thus using the word 'term' as the text you are searching for:

```
(^term$)|(^term\W)|(\Wterm\W)|(\Wterm$)
```

The first condition checks to make sure that term isn't the only contents of the blob, the second checks if its the first word, the third if it contained within the blob, and the last if its the last word.

If you want to consider any other characters as word characters (say a hyphen) you would need to repace the `\W` with `[^\w\-]`.

Hope this helps. There are probably optimizations that can performed as well, but this should at least be a good starting point.

Comment: He can also simply include the `^` and `$` in the `[]`

Comment: ^ inside [] means something else. And $ would map to the dollar sign.
You could however do something like (^|\W)(term)(\W|$)

Comment: @Gerben much better! But, thinking about it some more, this (and my previous pattern) now presents another issue: The non-word characters would also be included in the match. This will require additional logic to exclude them...

Comment: The below answer uses `\b`, which is a 0-length (so it doesn't add to your matched group) special symbol that indicates a word boundary (i.e. where `\w` meets `\W`, in either order). You might find that useful.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming all your glossary "words" consist of standard "word" characters, (i.e. `[A-Za-z0-9_]`), then a simple word boundary assertion can be placed before and after the word in the regex pattern. Try replacing the pertinant statement with this:

```php
$element->innertext = preg_replace(
    '/\b'. $glossary_word .'\b/i',
    '<a '. $glossary_tip .' >'. $glossary['word'] .'</a>',
    $element->innertext);
```

This assumes that `$glossary_word` has been run trough `preg_quote` (which your code does).

However, if the glossary words may contain other non-standard word characters (such as a `'-'` dash), a more complex regex can be formulated which incorporates lookahead and lookbehind to ensure that only whole words are matched. For example:

```php
$re_pattern = "/         # Match a glossary whole word.
    (?<=[\s'\"]|^)       # Word preceded by whitespace, quote or BOS.
    {$glossary_word}     # Word to be matched.
    (?=[\s'\".?!,;:]|$)  # Word followed by ws, quote, punct or EOS.
    /ix";
```

Comment: Yeah I had this trouble is that the words don't match the word format

Comment: @Richard Housham: The second, longer regex will work for _any_ word (or even a phrase containing spaces for that matter).

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem in JS getting individual words. What I did was the following (you can translate it from JS to PHP):

It actually works REALLY well for me. :)

```
var words = document.body.innerHTML;

// FIRST PASS

// remove scripts
words = words.replace(/<script[\s\S]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');
// remove CSS
words = words.replace(/<style[\s\S]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/style>/gi, '');
// remove comments
words = words.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g, '');
// remove html character entities
words = words.replace(/&.*?;/g, ' ');
// remove all HTML
words = words.replace(/<[\s\S]*?>/g, '');

// SECOND PASS

// remove all newlines
words = words.replace(/\n/g, ' ');
// replace multiple spaces with 1 space
words = words.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');

// split each word
words = words.split(/[^a-z-']+/gi);
```